# campare and store value in simple way using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a value in array of array and I want to fetch first value from this array

```
let test =
[[`abc`,`123`],
 [`pqr`,`456`],
 [`xyz`,`789`],
 [`mno`,`012`]]
```

and there is one output which look like this

```
let other=[{
 id:01,
 name:'abc'
},
{
 id:02,
 name:'xyz'
}]

other.map((value)=>{
console.log(value.name);
}
```

By this I got name from my other Output and I want to compare both the value of test and other and those the number output which is present inside test value

- for eg
  if `test[0]===value.name` then store number value
- eg

```
abc===abc then let number=123;
xyz===xyz then let number=789;
```

like this
is there any simplest way i can campare value of test and other and store the number

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact result you need, but you can use intermediate Map structure for an efficient search in `test`:

```js
const test =
[[`abc`,`123`],
 [`pqr`,`456`],
 [`xyz`,`789`],
 [`mno`,`012`]];

const testMap = new Map(test);

const other = [{
 id:01,
 name:'abc'
},
{
 id:02,
 name:'xyz'
}];

const otherWithTestInfo = other.map(
  value => ({ [value.name]: testMap.get(value.name) })
);

console.log(otherWithTestInfo);
```